# Fullscreen and volume buttons are hidden behind top bar, in youtubehelper in Swift

Tags: css, swift, youtube, youtube-api

While using youtube **'YouTubePlayer'** **cocoapod** for for iOS application.

After youtube updated their policy we have to show the title, avatar and share buttons in the top portion of YouTube view. because of this fullscreen and volume button hide behind these item.

**this screen from the iPhone6**

[image]

**How to show the fullscreen button like this below screen** 
because this is from the **iPhone5 screen**

[image]

Comment: same error. do you get any solution?

Comment: Please check my own answer for this, I have used the another library(youtubeplayer-in-wkwebview)

Comment: thanks, my solution is remove `showinfo` param then volume and fullscreen button came to control bar at bottom

Comment: @TanPham , with my experience it will show on some devices, with will not show on some device, so please check on iPhone5 and iPhoneX or iPhone8 Plus.
I have this on iPhone5 its showing these button but on iPhoneX these button are not showing. 
its YoutubePlayer is still using iFrame for iOS Library, may be you know that youtube element are created according to the screen size, with iFrame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this another [library](https://github.com/hmhv/YoutubePlayer-in-WKWebView)

which similar to the [youtube official iOS library](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper)

The only difference between these both is:

`youtube official library` using `WebView` 
which is causing the crashing issue in iOS 12.0.

where as `YoutubePlayer-in-WKWebView` this library using the `WebKit` this is working fine for me.

**Fullscreen** button is hide behind the title view, for this set the **playsinline** parameter to **0** then which enable the video can play in full screen mode.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue in another library. In my case, I removed the "showinfo" parameter in the settings, because it is deprecated.

Comment: But this doesn't affect anything on this issue.

Comment: @SumeetMourya could you please show your playerVars settings before load video method. I have "playsinline": "1","controls": "1"

Comment: `playerParams["showinfo"] = "0"`
        `playerParams["rel"] = "0"`
        `playerParams["modestbranding"] = "1"`
        `playerParams["playsinline"] = "0"`
        `playerParams["autohide"] = "1"`
        `playerParams["controls"] = "1"`

Comment: please try to remove playerParams["showinfo"] 
or set playerParams["showinfo"] = "1"

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did resolve the issue with another library which I mentioned in below answer. And `showinfo` this parameter is doesn’t matter now. The issue is full screen button shown behind the title section.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me, I was using the same library as @SumeetMourya and was still seeing the fullscreen button hidden behind the title, I had showinfo set to 0. Removing the "showinfo" or changing it to 1 put the fullscreen button in the lower control bar.